# Does "any" mean "all" or "one" for cards like Cheetah?

Tags: dc-comics-deck-building

Cheetah's ability is to "gain any card with cost 4 or less from the line-up." While playing the game the group has been split on whether this means take one card or take all cards.

There are some cards that specify to take all cards and I think some others specify to take one.

Comment: I think it means take 1, http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/894212/cheetahs-ability

Comment: semantically I would guess this means 'all'. If they meant one card I think they would have said 'gain **a** card with cost 4 or less from the line-up'

Comment: [This is a very active thread on the cryptozoic forum about rule clarifications.](http://forums.cryptozoic.com/showthread.php?t=21376&page=16) That is probably a better place to ask, since the R&D team seems to answer the questions there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this BGG thread](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/894212/cheetahs-ability) (which cites a play-tester), it means you can take any **one** card. At the end of the thread, game designer Matt Hyra (one of the co-designers for the game) corroborated this and added the following:

> Just as an FYI for future card reading: If a card gains "all" of something, it would be written like:
>
> Gain all card**s** with cost 4 or less from the Line-Up.

This is pretty common in card game terminology (citation needed I suppose?) where being able to take all cards would say "all" or similar.

Comment: Probably worth noting that one of the responses claims to be from an official play-tester, which adds some circumstantial weight to the ruling.

Comment: This was what I had originally posted as an answer until reread the counter argument in the same thread. Do you know why these counter arguments would be invalid? The counter argument examples were:
"The tazmanian devil destroys any object in his way"
or
"Homer Simpson will eat any junk food on his plate"

Comment: @ColinD I agree that it can mean "all" in some English sentences, although I think it's rare to see such a phrasing to mean all in any card-game wording that I've come across (hence my second sentence, which I admit is interpretative). The fact that "any **card**" is singular also suggests it means "one". (If it had said "any **cards**", you'd have been hard-pressed to argue it meant only one.)

Comment: @Johno I definitely agree with your answer and reasoning. However, I have not played this game, and by your post I assume you have not played either. The post you cited did not seem like it had any expert answers, which I guess is the gold standard here on stackexchange.

Comment: @ColinD Sure. I linked my source, which may or may not be conclusive enough for some people (if it hadn't had a comment from a supposed tester, I probably wouldn't have linked it). If another answer appears with a rulebook or FAQ quote, I highly expect it will (correctly) be voted above this answer as a more complete and conclusive answer. But if no such source exists, interpretation is all we have for now.